# Magento 2: How to get all products from category?

Tags: magento2, category, products, category-products

I want to give one link to browse the root category.
root category should load all products and with out tool bar.i found some articles for m1.
any one have idea?

Comment: You should accept answer to help other developers to find there solutions

Answer (score 1):

Inject **`Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory`** class to get product collection.

```
protected $categoryFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...    
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    ...
}

public function getCategoryProduct($categoryId)
{
    $category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
    $category->addAttributeToSelect('*')->getProductCollection();

    return $category;
}
```

Now call **getCategoryProduct()** in phtml file,

```
$categoryId = 10;
$getProudctcollection = $block->getCategoryProduct($categoryId);

foreach ($getProudctcollection as $product) {
    echo $product->getName(); //Get Product Name
    echo $product->getProductUrl(); //Get Product URL
}
```